# Downloading multiple log files

Tags: .net, f#, .net-core

This code succeeds in downloading log text files from multiple URLs. Can this be made more efficient?

```
let private downloadLogs toDirectory =

    let createFileDirectories (url : string) =
        let directory = $@"{toDirectory}\{url.Substring(13, 3)}"

        try
            if not (Directory.Exists(directory))
            then 
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directory) |> ignore
        with
            | ex -> failwith ex.Message

    let year = DateTime.Now.Year
    let month = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("d2")
    let day = DateTime.Now.Day

    let d01LogUrlWithDate = d01LogPartialUrl + $"{year}-{month}-{day}"
    let d02LogUrlWithDate = d02LogPartialUrl + $"{year}-{month}-{day}"
    let s01LogUrlWithDate = s01LogPartialUrl + $"{year}-{month}-{day}"
    let s02LogUrlWithDate = s02LogPartialUrl + $"{year}-{month}-{day}"

    let urlWithDateList = [d01LogUrlWithDate; d02LogUrlWithDate; s01LogUrlWithDate; s02LogUrlWithDate]

    // create folder for each url file
    urlWithDateList |> List.iter createFileDirectories

    let buildFinalUrlAndRequest number url =
        try
            let finalUrl =  if number = 0 then $"%s{url}-1.log" else $"%s{url}-{number}.log"
            printfn $"Searching for URL: {finalUrl}"
            let response = Http.AsyncRequestStream(finalUrl) |> Async.RunSynchronously
            if response.StatusCode >= 200 && response.StatusCode <= 299
            then 
                printfn $"URL Ready For Download: {url}"
                Ok response 
            else // this is never triggered
                printfn $"Error. Status Code: {response.StatusCode}"
                Error $"Status Code: {response.StatusCode}"
        with 
            | ex -> Error $"Request Error: {ex.Message}"

    let buildRequestList (state : seq<Result<HttpResponseWithStream, string>>) t =
        let range = seq{0..11}
        
        let responseSeq =
            seq{
                for num in range do
                    let numberUpdated = num + 1
                    let response = buildFinalUrlAndRequest numberUpdated t
                    response
            } 
        responseSeq |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x |> function | Ok _ -> true | Error _ -> false) |> Seq.append state

    let getResponse urls =
        urls 
        |> Seq.fold buildRequestList Seq.empty
        |> Seq.choose (fun x ->
            x |> function 
                | Ok response -> 
                    Some (async{
                        try
                            let fileName = Path.GetFileName(response.ResponseUrl.Replace(@"/", @"\"))
                            let subDir = response.ResponseUrl.Substring(13,3)
                            let pathName = $"""{toDirectory}\{subDir}\{fileName}"""
                            use outputFile = new FileStream(pathName, FileMode.Create)
                            do! response.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(outputFile) |> Async.AwaitTask
                            printfn $"File Downloaded: {pathName}"
                            return pathName
                        with
                            | ex -> 
                                printfn $"Download error {ex.Message}"
                                return ""
                    }) | _ -> None
        )

    urlWithDateList
    |> getResponse
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously |> Array.toList
```

Comment: In what way? Execution speed? Memory Usage? Code Verbosity? Idomaticism?

Comment: @Maslow Provide the best code review you can given the code. Optimize anything that you can see needs optimization and explain the trade offs.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be more options for parallelization and async here, and I think the fold overcomplicated what you were trying to do.

```fs
#if false
#r $"FSharp.Data"
#endif
open System.Net
open System.IO
open FSharp.Data

let  d01LogUrlWithDate, d02LogUrlWithDate, s01LogUrlWithDate, s02LogUrlWithDate = $"","","",""

module Async =
    let map f x =
        async {
            let! x' = x
            return f x'
        }
    let bind f x =
        async{
            let! x' = x
            return! f x'
        }
        
let private downloadLogs toDirectory =

    let createFileDirectories (url : string) =
        let directory = @"{toDirectory}\{url.Substring(13, 3)}"
        
        // if it is going to blow up, let it blow up keeping the entire stack trace
        if not <| Directory.Exists directory
        // I prefer strongly typed ignore, less prone to refactoring issues
        then  Directory.CreateDirectory directory |> ignore<DirectoryInfo>

    let urlWithDateList = // less clutter in scope
        let year = DateTime.Now.Year
        let month = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("d2")
        let day = DateTime.Now.Day
        [
            d01LogUrlWithDate
            d02LogUrlWithDate
            s01LogUrlWithDate
            s02LogUrlWithDate
        ] |> List.map (fun x -> x + $"{year}-{month}-{day}")

    // create folder for each url file
    urlWithDateList |> List.iter createFileDirectories

    let buildFinalUrlAndRequest number url =
        async {
        
            try // this area wasn't as complex, so I left the try alone
                // I'd think this should be $"%s{url}-{number+1}.log" or else 1 would stop on zero's output
                let finalUrl = if number = 0 then $"%s{url}-1.log" else $"%s{url}-{number}.log"
                printfn $"Searching for URL: {finalUrl}"
                let! response = FSharp.Data.Http.AsyncRequestStream finalUrl
                if response.StatusCode >= 200 && response.StatusCode <= 299
                then 
                    printfn $"URL Ready For Download: {url}"
                    return Ok response 
                else // this is never triggered
                    printfn $"Error. Status Code: {response.StatusCode}"
                    return Error $"Status Code: {response.StatusCode}"
            with 
                | ex -> return Error $"Request Error: {ex.Message}"
        }

    // if you are just throwing away the Result.Error options, then you don't need to use Results
    let buildRequestList t : seq<Async<Result<HttpResponseWithStream,string>>> =
        seq{0..11}
        |> Seq.map(fun i ->
            async {
                let numberUpdated = i + 1
                let! response = buildFinalUrlAndRequest numberUpdated t
                return response
            }
        )

    let getResponse urls =
        urls
        |> Seq.collect buildRequestList
        |> Async.Parallel
        // these two Async.map calls could be composed together
        |> Async.map(Seq.choose(function | Ok x -> Some x | _ -> None))
        |> Async.map (Seq.map (fun response ->
            async{
                let fileName = Path.GetFileName(response.ResponseUrl.Replace(@"/", "\"")) // fix syntax highlighting here on stack
                let subDir = response.ResponseUrl.Substring(13,3)
                let pathName = $@"{toDirectory}\{subDir}\{fileName}" // fix syntax highlighting here on Stack
                use outputFile = new FileStream(pathName, FileMode.Create)
                do! response.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(outputFile) |> Async.AwaitTask
                printfn $"File Downloaded: {pathName}"
                return pathName
            }
            |> Async.Catch // this way, no try needed above
            |> Async.map( // map the catch to option, and log the errors
                function
                | Choice1Of2 x -> Some x
                | Choice2Of2 ex -> printfn $"Download error {ex.Message}"; None
            )
        ))
        |> Async.bind Async.Parallel

    urlWithDateList
    |> getResponse
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> Seq.choose id // discard empty values
    |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: Excellent! I want to learn all that I can in regards to writing idiomatic and efficient F# code. Thanks.